# Vertical Slides Break Presentation in Reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

I keep having the same issue-- After creating a set of vertical slides in Reveal.js, using the nested

```
<section>
<section>Content</section>
<section>Content</section>
</section>
```

the next slide after that vertical list doesn't work right. My code editor doesn't recognize it as HTML and it displays the new slide content ON ALL SLIDES, not in the regular Reveal.js formatting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following structure:

```
<section>
 <section>
    <h3>First slide with vertical</h3>
 </section>
 <section>
    <h4>First vertical slide</h4>
 </section>
 <section>
    <h4>Second vertical slide</h4>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. In my case my HTML was somethign similar to

```
   <section>
      <h1>Some heading</h1>
      <section>Content</section>
      <section>Content</section>
    </section>
```

The additional html was causing the issue and showing up in every slide. I think for vertical slides the nesting has to be immediate.

```
   <section>
      <section>Content</section>
      <section>Content</section>
    </section>
```

I had to remove the html content that was added between the `section tag` and `section tag`at the second level.